# Join string inputs without creating newline

Tags: python, python-3.x, join

Width, Height and Depth of small box: `1x1x1`

Width, Height and Depth of big box: `3x3x3`

Number of `1x1x1` that will fit in `3x3x3` box is: `27`

I have an exercise like that using python3 to get the outcome.

I did:

```
sb = input("Width, Height and Depth of small box: ")

s= 'x'
```

And then use `print(s.join(sb))`, but i then create new line with 1x1x1 after type 111 and enter which i do not want. I just want it to be exact on the same line of W, H and D of small box (of course with the join).

But the grading system from my student learning not only decline the answer with newline for 1x1x1, they also stated that the error as "1xxx1xxx1". But it is exactly 1x1x1 on the newline.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can format multiple inputs from one string:

```
sb = input("Width, Height and Depth of small box separated by |: ")
# User enters 3|3|3

s = 'x'.join(sb.split('|'))

print(s)
# 3x3x3
```

We use `|` as an arbitrary delimiter since it is unlikely it will be used for any other purpose.

Comment: Thanks for that. However if i print x, it would be on newline which is incorrect compared to the question :( How can i fix this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. when you print, the output `3x3x3` will be on one line.

Comment: i mean on the same line as Width, height and Depth of small box :( . And also when i do print for final line, i cannot divide 3x3x3 and 1x1x1 since both have integer and string which is x. What should i also have to do here? Really appreciate!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Try editing your question with a *concrete* example. Specify the line in the full program which does something you don't expect / want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
eval('1x1x1'.replace('x', '*'))
#1
eval('3x3x3'.replace('x', '*'))
#27
```

and then divide these 2 results as:

```
eval('3x3x3'.replace('x', '*')) / eval('1x1x1'.replace('x', '*'))
```

However, it is not a good practice.